# Using start to run node application on startup

Tags: upstart

I have a problem with the node_module-path. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Running

```
exec sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/node /etc/node/app.js
```

gives me

```
Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
```

I have this config (/etc/init/applicationserver.conf):

```
start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
    export HOME="/"
    export NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/node_modules"

    exec sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/node /etc/node/app.js >> /var/log/applicationserver.log 2>&1
end script

post-start script

end script
```

It seems like it can't find the modules installed. I've verified that connect is under /usr/lib/node_modules and if I export NODE_PATH from root or my account it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, not the best way to be starting something in
general. A wrapper script with the correct ownership
could do the same work without sudo.

You're problem is in the use of sudo, regardless of
the context as an upstart job. The environmental vars
you're defining aren't being passed on. Add the
'-E' switch to sudo to correct this.

If you used a wrapper owned by www-data to start that
process you wouldn't have this problem because you
wouldn't have needed sudo. There are lots of example
jobs that create vars and pass them on to the 
new child process. It's a basic property of fork/clone.

Comment: I'm all ears on if there is a better way to start it. Any suggestions? I'm quite the noob on these things.

Comment: Btw, the -E made it work. When thinking of it, it seems logic that the env vars don't follow by default.

Comment: How about this?
    cat js-wrapper.sh 
    #!/bin/sh
    /usr/bin/node /etc/node/app.js >> /var/log/applicationserver.log 2>&1

chown www-data:root js-wrapper.sh

and run that instead?

Comment: I'll do that. Just a final question. why www-data:root and not www-data:www-data or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Just not leaving it to chance. This is basic Unix system administration and there is plenty of documentation on the subject.
http://tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/index.html

Comment: how do i add multiple answer? :)